# Can't send '#' (hash/pound) to another page using GET?

Tags: php, html, get

I am trying to send a form to another page and my value has # in it but I Have noticed that whatever comes after # is not considered value and is not part of the GET values.

Is there a hack around or a solution to send data using method `GET` while the string starts with a `#`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`#` starts the fragment, which is not sent to the server.

You **need** to correctly URL-encode your data, e.g. by using the [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function.

Comment: It starts the [URI fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Urlencode might not work for # in Firefox. You can try string replace instead,

$str = str_replace("#", "%23", $str);